# Setting proxy on .Rprofile on OSX fails

Tags: macos, r, proxy, rprofile

In order to access CRAN packages from within R on OSX I've been using

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://blah_blah:1234/")
```

as the first command in the R GUI for a while, but would really like to set this proxy automatically.

I've tried unsuccessfully to get the same command to work in a .Rprofile file in ~/

I've also tried `http_proxy="http://blah_blah:1234/"`, but this fails too.

The error I get when I try to view packages is a drop-down window that says:

```
Fetching Package List Failed
Please consult R Console output for details
```

The GUI then gives:

```
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : Line starting '<head> ...' is malformed!
```

The .Rprofile file itself seems to be loading (checked using `cat("my profile works\n"))`

Comment: Would someone create an rprofile tag? There are now a few questions  that are directly related to the rprofile

Comment: After you start R, what happens when you type: `Sys.getenv("http_proxy")`

Comment: If it is to set the repository for downloading packages, you can just use `options("repos"="http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/")` in the profile file.

Comment: @csgillespie Sys.getenv("http_proxy") returns http_proxy ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just use .First ?

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Customizing-the-environment

Comment: I tried first, within .Rprofile, but couldn't get it to work - is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This thread appears first when searching for setting R proxy on OS X, so here's what I use in my .Rprofile:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy=system("networksetup -getwebproxy Ethernet | awk {'print $2'} | awk {'getline l2; getline l3; print \"http://\"l2\":\"l3'} | head -n 1",intern=TRUE))
```

Change **Ethernet** to **Airport** if necessary.

Credit for the awk part goes to [Chealion](https://superuser.com/questions/48480/how-can-i-get-mac-os-xs-proxy-information-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to solve this using trial and error...

A combination of .First *and* Sys.setenv() works.

If anyone has any ideas I'd be interested to know why.